# Terminal Output Redirected to a File

Tags: command-line, minicom

I am redirecting the output of the terminal to a file using:

```
Command > File.txt
```

but the contents of the file appear like this:

[image]

What is the problem? How can I make them appear normal?

Comment: The command might be colouring its output. Which command is it?

Comment: The command is minicom.

Comment: According to [this](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_), that's the sequence to set the cursor row and column to (23,80) and (24,17). Not sure why it is printing that, though.

Comment: In general, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684/70524 for a robust way of removing xterm control sequences from output. I think there should be way to convince minicom to avoid outputing these, but I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

The command you're executing (`minicom`) is using "VT100 Escape Sequences" to do cursor positioning.

To remove the characters listed above, pipe the file through

```
sed -e 's/^[\[[0-9][0-9];[0-9][0-9]H//'
#         ^^ actual ESCape
```

I got the Escape by typing <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Those are terminal escape sequences, to be interpreted by the terminal driver. As the output from the program is being saved to a file, the (`minicom`) program rather erroneously dumping the escape sequences too without checking where it's STDOUT is going.

To get rid of the escape sequences, using `sed` to remove the lines that contain `23;80H`, dry-run:

```
sed '/23;80H/d' file.txt
```

Modification:

```
sed -i '/23;80H/d' file.txt
```

If you wish to keep a backup with an extension e.g. `.bak`, do:

```
sed -i.bak '/23;80H/d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you haven't set **character encoding** of output file to **UTF-8**.

> In case you cannot change **/etc/*** files,
>
> you can manually set the **gnome-terminal** menu **Terminal|Set Character
>   Encoding** to **Unicode(Utf-8)**

Answer obtained from this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly)